# Convert from nvarchar to decimal and filter by range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to perform a query on these string values:

```
Record ID / Value
1 / 10.5
2 / 12
3 / 8
4 / 19.25
5 / 16.4
6 / 14
```

The value column is a nvarchar column. I would like to filter the results between two string values inserted by users (for example 10 and 15). I tried to use:

```
SELECT Value 
FROM Table 
WHERE CONVERT(decimal(10, 2), Value) 
    BETWEEN CONVERT(decimal(10, 4), '10') 
    AND CONVERT(decimal(10, 4), '15')
```

But I have the following error:

```
Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.
```

What is wrong with the data types?

Comment: Try `SELECT CONVERT(decimal(10, 2), Value) from Table`, what happens?

Comment: The problem here is your storing a numeric value as a `varchar`; thus someone has inserted a value isn't isn't numerical. The first step is to identify the bad data: `SELECT [value] FROM [Table] WHERE CONVERT_TRY(decimal(6,2),[value]) IS NULL;`. Also store your data in a datatype that is representative of the data, just use `(n)varchar` for things like dates, numbers, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `TRY_CONVERT` (SQL Server 2012 and newer):

```
SELECT Value 
FROM Table 
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(decimal(10, 2),Value) BETWEEN TRY_CONVERT(decimal(10, 4), '10') 
                                            AND TRY_CONVERT(decimal(10, 4), '15')
```

---

Better approach is to add computed column:

```
CREATE TABLE tab(
   value VARCHAR(100),
   value_as_decimal AS (TRY_CONVERT(decimal(10, 2),Value)) PERSISTED
);

CREATE INDEX tab_ix ON tab(value_as_decimal) INCLUDE(Value);

SELECT Value 
FROM Table 
WHERE value_as_decimal BETWEEN TRY_CONVERT(decimal(10, 4), '10') 
                           AND TRY_CONVERT(decimal(10, 4), '15');
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=8fff1d00354572dd95a1c01f614e7d3c)**

Ideal solution is to store value as `DECIMAL(10,4)` and forget about casting.